# external CSS in simple webpage designing sometime working, sometime not in my laptop, any reason?

Tags: html, css

```css
        body
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            min-height: 100vh;
            background-color: #333;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-family: consolas;
        }

        .container
        {
            width: 1000px;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        .card
        {
            position: relative;

        }

        .card .face
        {
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }

        .card .face1
        {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #333;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            z-index: 1;
            transform: translateY(100px);
        }

        .card:hover .face1
        {
            transform: translateY(0);
        }

        .card .face2
        {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #fff;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            box-shadow: 0 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            transform: translateY(-100px);
        }

        .card:hover .face2
        {
            transform: translateY(0);
        }

        .card .content p 
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;

        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Card Design</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="face face1">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="home.png">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="face face2">
                <div class="content">
                    <p>dfhj dkcfbjkfdcjbh fkcjbhfc.l igJSz/dfilbdo igjd;ofijvodlkjs spdjivorghosdje.kd oslghodf</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#">Read More...</a>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="face face1">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="home.png">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="face face2">
                <div class="content">
                    <p>dfhj dkcfbjkfdcjbh fkcjbhfc.l igJSz/dfilbdo igjd;ofijvodlkjs spdjivorghosdje.kd oslghodf</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#">Read More...</a>
            </div>  
        </div>      

        <div class="card">
            <div class="face face1">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="home.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="face face2">
                <div class="content">
                    <p>dfhj dkcfbjkfdcjbh fkcjbhfc.l igJSz/dfilbdo igjd;ofijvodlkjs spdjivorghosdje.kd oslghodf</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#">Read More...</a>
            </div>  
        </div>          
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I placed html(index.html) and CSS(style.css) file in the same directory many times i crosschecked **link** tag sometime it runs correctly but sometimes CSS is not working anyone can help me, please!

I Posted My both files in JS/HTML/CSS Snippet this is simple card design that expand on hover on it this program also outputs correctly here but in my laptop it sometimes not gaining CSS properties

Comment: Would it be possible to place your code into a runnable snippet so that the problem can be diagnosed?

Comment: @karolus i am new on this community can you suggest me where i can place my code

Comment: Check your permissions on your files. Should be 755 or 644.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a quick check of your code—on macOS with Firefox and Safari, looks to be fine. Is there any type of error you are seeing? Per file permissions, it shouldn't be an issue if you are loading these from a common documents folder on your system.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: consolas;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
}

.card .face {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card .face1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(100px);
}

.card:hover .face1 {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.card .face2 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}

.card:hover .face2 {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.card .content p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="face face1">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="home.png">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="face face2">
      <div class="content">
        <p>dfhj dkcfbjkfdcjbh fkcjbhfc.l igJSz/dfilbdo igjd;ofijvodlkjs spdjivorghosdje.kd oslghodf</p>
      </div>
      <a href="#">Read More...</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="face face1">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="home.png">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="face face2">
      <div class="content">
        <p>dfhj dkcfbjkfdcjbh fkcjbhfc.l igJSz/dfilbdo igjd;ofijvodlkjs spdjivorghosdje.kd oslghodf</p>
      </div>
      <a href="#">Read More...</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="face face1">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="home.png">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="face face2">
      <div class="content">
        <p>dfhj dkcfbjkfdcjbh fkcjbhfc.l igJSz/dfilbdo igjd;ofijvodlkjs spdjivorghosdje.kd oslghodf</p>
      </div>
      <a href="#">Read More...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```